# Solving an equation containing an integral in the unknowns

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I have an equation of $x$ and $y$, which reads
$$
-\alpha^2+\frac{2}{3} \alpha^3+y^2-\frac{2}{3}y^3+x^3f(\frac{y}{x})=0,
$$

where $\alpha$ is positive parameter and $f(x)=\int (1-\tanh x) x^2\mathrm{d}x$, with the arbitrary constant of integration defined by $f(\infty)=0$. With *Mathematica*, $f(x)$ is just what *Mathematica* gives you.

Now I want to obtain the relation between $x$ and $y$ from that equation, with $x\in(0,1/\ln 2)$, the parameter $\alpha$ should be tested for $\alpha\in(0,5)$, say, especially the values around $2.4$

### My Attempt

My attempt is to use `FindRoot` to do that job, however no matter how I increase the `WorkingPrecision`, there are complains saying:

> The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified     by `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` but was unable to find a sufficient     decrease in the merit function. You may need more than 100 digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

The curve obtained is just wearied, which I can't trust. For your convenience, I will put my attempt code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
α = 15/10;
stepSize = 1/100;
c0 = Log[2];
eps = 1/100000;
f[x_] = Integrate[(1 - Tanh[x]) x^2, x]; (*f(∞)=0*)
list = 
  Table[
    {c0 x, 
     y /. FindRoot[
            -α^2 + 2/3*α^3 + y^2 - 2/3 y^3 + x^3 f[y/x] == 0, 
            {y, 0.5}, 
            WorkingPrecision -> 100]}, 
    {x, eps, 1/c0, stepSize}];
ListLinePlot[list]
```

The above code gives a wearied curve as shown below and a lot of complains as mentioned above.

[image]

I've also tried the fix $y$ to solve for $x$ instead. However, the code doesn't works well (for some parameters), either.

Comment: There is more than one `y` for each `x`, and depending on the initial guess, you will jump between those different roots. Here is a [contour plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EGZht.png) of your function for the choice of alpha shown in your post, with the zero-contour only shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you want, here's how I would go about this. First, using your choice of `α`, define

```
α = 15/10;
f[x_] = Integrate[(1 - Tanh[x]) x^2, x]
(* -x^2 Log[1+E^(-2 x)]+x PolyLog[2,-E^(-2 x)]+1/2 PolyLog[3,-E^(-2 x)] *)
g[x_, y_] = -α^2 + 2/3*α^3 + y^2 - 2/3 y^3 + x^3 f[y/x];
```

Generate the zero-contours of your function for your choice of `α` using  `ContourPlot`:

```
p1 = ContourPlot[g[x, y] /. α -> 15/10
  , {x, 0, 1/Log[2]}, {y, -5, 5}
  , Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

This might be all you want! If you want the points, extract them:

```
pts = First@Cases[Normal@p1, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity];
ListLinePlot@pts
```

[image]

These aren't perfect, so let's use these points as initial guesses for `FindRoot` to refine the values:

```
newPts = {#1, y /. FindRoot[g[#1, y] /. α -> 15/10, {y, #2}]} & @@@ pts;
ListLinePlot@newPts
```

[image]

Comment: I need to carefully read this, your results seems very good! In the mean time, can you explain what zero contour means?

Comment: I just mean that it's the level-curve of the the function that you're setting to zero (which I'm calling `g`) that corresponds to the value `0`. In other words, it's the graph of the solution set of `g[x, y] == 0`.

Comment: pts = First@Cases[Normal@p1, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity]; In this code, you select the line (points) in the objects Normal@p1, what other things other than line does this Normal@p1 have?

Comment: Everything in *Mathematica* is an expression, including `Graphics`. Evaluate `p1` and then evaluate `p1 // FullForm`, and you will see all the stuff associated with that `Graphics` object. Doing `Normal@p1` first rearranges the innards of the expression to more directly reflect what's being drawn in the figure; this is necessary because `Graphics` expressions typically are written in terms of `GraphicsComplex`es, which (I think) is for the purposes of compression. Anyway, I recommend playing! Make a simple like  `Plot[{x^2, 1+x^2}, {x, 0, 1}] //Normal//FullForm` and examine the results!